# How to use i18next as a peer dependency for my component library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internationalization, i18next, react-i18next

I am building a React component library which contains some translations, but I want these translations to be provided by the user of my package.

The reason for this is that these translations should be customizable, and I don't want to include every possible language in this package.

So what I'd like to achieve is to use `useTranslations` inside my component library like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

const MyComponent = () => {
    const { t } = useTranslation();

    return <div>{t('helloWorld')}</div>;
};
```

And somehow the `'helloWorld'` translations should be configurable by the user of the library.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this was caused by `yarn link` using two versions of `react-i18next`.

To solve this I've configured my app to use the `react-i18next` version of my package:

```sh
cd my-package/node_modules/react-i18next
yarn link

cd my-app
yarn link react-i18next
```

Now my package uses the `i18next` instance configured in my app.